# Is there a SE site where sci-fi recommendation questions are on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I would like to read some hard sci-fi novels, the more plausible from a scientific point of view, the better. I've read good reviews about Larry Niven and David Brin's books.

Of course questions asking for further recommendations are off-topic on Science Fiction & Fantasy but is there an SE site where it would be on-topic? After all there's a Software Recommendations SE site (with low traffic), so I was wondering if there was also a (sci-fi) book recommendation SE site.

If not, would it be impolite to ask (here on Meta, of course: not on the main site) about resources on the Internet where I could ask such a question?

Comment: Amazon offers [suggested reads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p38Rn.png) at the bottom of every book page. Might I suggest you just plug in your favourite books and keep a note of the recommendations it offers.

Comment: Related: [What is a good site for book recommendations?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1080/21267)

Comment: There is occasionally good stuff in [tag:story-identification], but don't expect anything tailored to your personal taste.

Comment: Describe the story you want to read, add the "story identification" tag and tadaaam you can use this site as a recommendation site !

Comment: (this is a joke)

Comment: [This author recommendation service](http://www.gnooks.com/) came up in The Reading Room (Lit.SE chat room)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### There is no such site on the SE network

You're absolutely correct that "recommendation" questions are off-topic here; we even have a custom off-topic close reason for them. The only other remotely plausible site would be the new [Literature Beta](https://literature.stackexchange.com/), but the [consensus](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2) over there is also that recommendations are off-topic. You could always suggest a site for book recommendations on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), but there is of course no guarantee that it would take off.

Moving outside the Q&A sites, your best bet would be:

- Our main [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley)
- Non-SE websites, such as Reddit (which has [at](https://www.reddit.com/r/booksuggestions/) least [two](https://www.reddit.com/r/suggestmeabook/) book suggestion subreddits)

Comment: Thanks! I will try the chat, and if unsuccessful, I will try on Reddit (never used it much, apart from AMAs I was very interested in, but it could be a start!).

Comment: There was a "Recommendations" proposal on Area51 about a year or so ago.  it didn't get off the ground.

Comment: @Chenmunka I'm not surprised. It's not easy to open Recommendation sites on SE - it's not impossible, but (expecially for something so subjective as literature preferences) it's very difficult to make it fit in the general structure of a Q&A site, where there should be "one right answer" (or few of them) to each question.

Comment: I've always hesitated to ask for recommendations in chat, for fear of turning it into a recommendations-swamp. Are recommendation requests well-received?

Comment: @MissMonicaE - sure. Pop in, say 'does anyone know of a book like this that I would be interested in', hopefully get an answer, and chat will go on, discussing everything from squirrels to literature.se to toilet paper tubes. Don't worry about turning the chat into a swamp - if it becomes a problem, we'll probably create a specific chat room for book recommendations.