# Ask for related books on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I liked *Ready Player One* and wanted to know if asking for related books would be on topic or not. Is it?

(Have not used this SE in a while)

Comment: [Is there a SE site where sci-fi recommendation questions are on-topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10605/is-there-a-se-site-where-sci-fi-recommendation-questions-are-on-topic) - Spoiler. No there isn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Such a question would be entirely off-topic and would be closed in very short order. Per the [FAQ](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> Not all questions have a home on Stack Exchange. Please note the following types of questions are off-topic here:
>
> **Reading or viewing recommendations: I liked X, what should I watch next?**

Answer (score 6):

As **@Valorum** wrote, asking on SFF.SE is off-topic per FAQ, however, you can still use the advantage of the many fantasy/science fiction enthusiasts and ask for book recommendations in the main chat, [The Restaurant at the End of the Universe.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe)

I did so myself previously and got a few good recommendations of fantasy series.